# MySQL: Trying to get the number of registered users for the past 6 months in array format

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress and Mysql.

I need to output the number of registered users via Chart.js and for that I need the number of registered users for each month, let's say month 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Currently I run 6 MySQL queries to get this information. They are:

```
    $sqlmonth0 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users WHERE YEAR(user_registered)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH)) AND MONTH(user_registered)= MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH))";
    $sqlmonth1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users WHERE YEAR(user_registered)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND MONTH(user_registered)= MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))";
    // and so on... for 6  more sql queries. Then
   $month0=$wpdb->get_results($sqlmonth0);
   $month1=$wpdb->get_results($sqlmonth1);
```

Is this efficient? I'm thinking about some code that gets an array of all registered people in the month in the following format:

```
$registeredusers = array($month0,$month1,$month2,$month3)
```

which also equals `$registeredusers = $wpdp->get_results($sql)`

but what is such `$sql` code?

As you can see if I do this daily, I will need to compute over 180 SQL queries, which get's inefficient my way and also looks horrible in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Group By. For information on Group By, you may checkout [Mysql Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Your query should look something like below. Add where clause for date as per requirement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CONCAT(YEAR(user_registered),",",MONTH(user_registered)) AS YearMonth FROM wp_users GROUP BY Year(user_registered), Month(user_registered)
```